# Looping in java

Tags: java

I know this is weird, I want do this way and I couldn't find a solution which is why asking you guys! I've methods like which I'm calling inside a class as listed below - 
//

```
     @Test
     Key.chooseNew(0);
     Key.navigate_toNew(1);
     Key.send_keys_loginNew(2);
     Key.logoutNew(3);
```

How can I run it in a loop in java replacing those numbers or such things doesn't exist?!

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a different method on each line so there is no loop.

The only pattern I can see is:

```
int i = 0;
Key.chooseNew(i++);
Key.navigate_toNew(i++);
Key.send_keys_loginNew(i++);
Key.logoutNew(i++);
```

Comment: you didnt need to increment the last one. i=4 in that case. could cause an issue if it is used elsewhere.

Comment: True :) I find it nicer this way anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Reflection in java. You could save the names of the methods to be called in a list in the order you want them called and then inside the loop you can call the method with the method name using `obj.getClass().getMethod()` as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string).

Hope this is what you were looking for.